# What is the benefit of coins in Mario Kart 8?

Tags: mario-kart-8

In Mario Kart 8, what is the benefit of coins you pick up while racing?
You can't have more than 10 at any given time.
Are there benefits for having 1-9 coins?
Or do you only get benefits when you are maxed out at 10?

How does this system work?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Coins have three benefits, speed, boosts and unlocks.

**Speed**

> Each coin you collect boosts your overall speed. Increasing your top speed, especially on straightaways. You max out at 10 coins.

**Boosts**

> For each coin you collect you get a very, very tiny speed boost -- even after you've collected the maximum of 10 coins.

**Unlocks**

> You must collect coins to unlock karts and parts. Each coin you collect adds to an overall coin count.

[Source](http://www.ign.com/wikis/mario-kart-8/Coins)