# Do coins from item boxes count towards total coins collected?

Tags: mario-kart-8

Mario Kart 8 has coins scattered about the track which [make you go faster and contribute to unlocking kart customisations](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/170084/69998). Coins can also be obtained from item boxes - there's one item that gives you 2 coins when activated. These (obviously) contribute to making you go faster, but do they contribute to customisation unlocks?

Comment: If it's anything like MK7, only the coins you have on hand when the race ends count. If so (which I am not currently sure), then the source of the coins would not matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

The number of coins added to your total is the number of coins that each local player has at the end of each race. Regardless of how you collected a coin, if you have it at the end of the race, it counts.

For more details see the [Mario Kart 8 Total Coins Collecting Logic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/173437/mario-kart-8-total-coins-collecting-logic/173582) question.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

**All** coins contribute to item unlocks, including coins from item boxes.