# Mario Kart 8 Total Coins Collecting Logic

Tags: mario-kart-8

How do the total coins add up?

Every time I collect one or only the ones I'm holding at the end of the race? In the latter case, it would always take at least 5 races (5 * 10 = 50) to unlock something since holding coins is limited to 10.

I assume it's the first case though since I possibly unlocked a new part after a Grand Prix (= 4 races).

Comment: Not sure for this game, but in MK7 it was "coin count at end of race".

Answer (score 7):

**The number of coins added to your total is the number of coins that each local player has at the end of each race.** This means that you can get a maximum of 10 coins per race with one player, but 40 coins per race with four players.

Although you can collect enough coins to unlock multiple parts in a single grand prix or VS match, you can only unlock one part at a time. You must then return the the menu after viewing the newly unlocked part to receive any further parts that you have enough total coins to unlock.

Answer (score 1):

It's the coins collected at the end of the race. It can be possible that you have multiple unlocks in a row after a grand prix, for example if you start with 95 coins.

1. After grand prix 1, you *can* have 135 coins, and unlocked something
2. After grand prix 2, you *can* have 175 coins, and unlocked something
3. After grand prix 3, you *can* have 205 coins, and unlocked something

After GP4 it stops, but in one grand prix you have again a coin amount just under 50, so you'll unlock again in a row. If you quit or restart the grand prix after a few races, you still obtained some coins. Therefor it isn't necessary to get 40 coins every grand prix.

Comment: Also note that all players contribute, so if you (for example) do a 32-race VS series with 3 players, you can get up to 960 coins (but you can't unlock more than one thing at once, they'll get bufferedone at a time).

Comment: If you play and "rage-quit", will it still count your current points towards your total score?

Comment: Good question. I have no idea. If you quit the game normally (via the menu ingame) I think it is done, because I was awarded a couple of times with a new customization. When you throw the controller away, unplug the Wii U, I guess it is not awarded. If it is awarded between races in a Grand Prix, I don't know