# Are coins awarded between races in a Grand Prix?

Tags: wii-u, mario-kart-8

A follow-up question from [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/173437/mario-kart-8-total-coins-collecting-logic). The main question is:

> Are coins saved to your account at the end of the race, or at the end of a Grand Prix, in Mario Kart 8 (or every Mario Kart, for that matter)

'We' always talk about coins awarded every race, because then it is determined how much you *should* earn, but is it also saved at that moment to your account?

For example, you collect 10 coins in race 1, 5 in race 2. Half-way during race 3 you have 7 coins, but I remember the pizza in the oven is done, and I have to eat. Because I can't play MK8 during pizza eating, I quit the game from the in-game menu, and turn off the Wii U. How much coins do I have extra then:

- 0, because the GP isn't finished
- 15, because that is the amount of coins collected in *finished* races
- 22, because that is the amount of coins collected in *finished* races and the amount I have in this race

In the first two cases, rage quitting would not result in a lower coin amount, but the third option will. However, the third option would be exploitable, by starting a GP (with 5 coins) and quit immediately. Of course it is more fun by playing, but this way coin grinding is a lot faster (and you need 10000 coins for the [Gold Glider](http://www.ign.com/wikis/mario-kart-8/Gold_Glider)

Comment: This seems to be sufficiently answered in the linked question. Coins are collected (based on the totals of each local player) at the **end** *of each race*.

Comment: @TrentHawkins You are correct. I made the question clearer. I'm asking between the difference between awarded and actually getting. For example if my girlfriend says she'll give me 5 bucks tomorrow, but ragequits in the evening, I didn't get my 5 bucks, even though she promised it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of the three options presented, the second one (15 coins) is how it to works. As stated by @Brian's answer in the linked question (emphasis mine):

> The number of coins *added to your total* is the number of coins that each local player has at the ***end*** of each race.

I can confirm this through my efforts to achieve gold on every single Mirror Grand Prix. When I quit the race after the second or third track (Usually due to the dirty cheatin' CPUs), and still being awarded periodic coin-related kart parts. That rules out situation 1 (0 coins).

Situation 3 (22 coins) is ruled out by my efforts to beat the staff ghost on a couple of tracks where it's nearly impossible to get a time on the leading edge of the bell curve unless you race *perfectly*. Despite restarting a few dozen times (not counting the failed starting boosts), no amount of coin collecting in those aborted time-trials resulted in kart part unlocks when I eventually needed to quit out to the start menu to cool my head.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, though not completely for me. The second case seemed like the most likely one, the most fair and 'natural'. However I was not sure, but this clarifies it. If there are no other awarding scenarios (I think not), it is indeed option 2